# Will A* in AMCL direct robot into grey area on map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, pgm, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to edit the map produced by a SLAM algorithm, to add in no go areas. These areas do not ave a physical barrier. Would greying them out be sufficient to prevent the A* algorithm used by AMCL from directing the robot into them?

If not, how would one accomplish this?

Also, can AMCL make use of .png maps, or does it have to be the default pgm?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282511/will-a*-in-amcl-direct-robot-into-grey-area-on-map/) by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've manually edited maps using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) and had great success with keeping planners from making paths through unwanted areas. I used *black* instead of gray as that corresponds to "very" occupied. From [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#Image_format):

> When comparing to the threshold parameters, the occupancy probability of an image pixel is computed as follows: `occ = (255 - color_avg) / 255.0`, where `color_avg` is the 8-bit value that results from averaging over all channels, e.g. if the
> image is 24-bit color, a pixel with the color `0x0a0a0a` has a probability of 0.96, which is very occupied. The color
> `0xeeeeee` yields 0.07, which is very unoccupied.

As black is `0x000000` it should yield 100% (or very) occupied. Gray may not result in an area being considered occupied.

---

**Edit:**

According to the wiki that I linked to, you can use a PNG instead of PGM, but PNG is not supported on OS X.

As @Procópio stated in the comments

> painting the map black will have the
> side-effect of degrading localization,
> as the real LIDAR measurements will
> not match those of the edited map.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-12**:
Note that AMCL is not going to be planning any paths for you. It will localize your robot, but not generate any paths.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2018-02-13**:
painting the map black will have the side-effect of degrading localization, as the real LIDAR measurements will not match those of the edited map.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-13**:
@Procópio: good point

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2018-02-13**:
Yes, i said A* in AMCL.
I agree with Procòpio, black denotes a physical barrier tat is not there in the real world and will affect the localisation. Surely the A* used would not direct the robot into unexplored territory?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-13**:\

> Please do not comment if you do not have anything constructive to add

?